# Javascript Fundamentals : Simple Calculator Error

Tags: javascript

I have an exercise to perform Simple Calculation using Javascript. The code works fine in Visual Studio but not in the Hackerrank test site that i have to do the exercise in.

**HTML Code: (Given already, cannot modify) :**

```
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Simple Calculation</TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <FORM NAME="myForm">
        <TABLE BORDER=2>
            <TR>
                <TD align="center">
                    <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="screen" NAME="screen" style="width:99%"><br>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="7" VALUE="  7  " onclick="update(7)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="8" VALUE="  8  " onclick="update(8)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="9" VALUE="  9  " onclick="update(9)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="+" VALUE="  +  " onclick="update('+')">
                    <br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="4" VALUE="  4  " onclick="update(4)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="5" VALUE="  5  " onclick="update(5)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="6" VALUE="  6  " onclick="update(6)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="-" VALUE="  -  " onclick="update('-')">
                    <br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="1" VALUE="  1  " onclick="update(1)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="2" VALUE="  2  " onclick="update(2)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="3" VALUE="  3  " onclick="update(3)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="*" VALUE="  x  " onclick="update('*')">
                    <br>
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="c" VALUE="  c  " onclick="form_reset();">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="0" VALUE="  0  " onclick="update(0)">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="=" VALUE="  =  " onclick="result();">
                    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="/" VALUE="  /  " onclick="update('/')">
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </FORM>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**JS file that i can modify.I cannot remove the various functions or add a new one**

```
var text = "";
function update(value) {
    //Type the code here.
    text+= value;
    document.getElementById('screen').value = value;
}

function result() {
    //Type the code here.
    document.getElementById('screen').value = eval(text);
}

function form_reset() {
    //Type the code here.
    document.getElementById('screen').value ="";
    text = "";
}
```

When i run the test, its validating against below test cases. It's failing in the function result(); while adding 7 and 8

```
describe('Calc Handson', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML='<TABLE BORDER=2 id="app"><TR><TD align="center"><INPUT TYPE="text" ID="screen" NAME="screen" style="width:99%"><br>   </TD> </TR> <TR><TD> <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="7" VALUE="  7  " onclick="update(7)">  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="8" VALUE="  8  " onclick="update(8)"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="9"VALUE="  9  " onclick="update(9)"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="+" VALUE="  +  " onclick="update("+")"><br><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="4" VALUE="  4  " onclick="update(4)">  <INPUTTYPE="button" NAME="5" VALUE="  5  " onclick="update(5)"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="6" VALUE="  6  " onclick="updat(6)"> <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="-" VALUE="  -  " onclick="update("-")"><br><INPUTTYPE="button" NAME="1" VALUE="  1  " onclick="update(1)"> <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="2" VALUE="  2  " onclick="update(2)"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="3" VALUE="  3  " onclick="update(3)"> <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="*"VALUE="  x  " onclick="update("*")"><br> <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="c" VALUE="  c  "onclick="form_reset();">   <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="0" VALUE="  0  " onclick="update(0)">  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="=" VALUE="  =  " onclick="result();"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="/" VALUE="  /  " onclick="update("/")">             </TD></TR> </TABLE>';

    });

    afterEach(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('app'));
    });

    describe('Calc ', function() {
         it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(1);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('1');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(2);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('2');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(3);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('3');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(4);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('4');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(5);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('5');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(6);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('6');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(7);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('7');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(8);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('8');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(9);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('9');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update(0);
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('0');

        });

it('update function should exist', function() {
            update('*');
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('*');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update('+');
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('+');

        });

it('update function should exist', function() {
            update('-');
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('-');

        });
it('update function should exist', function() {
            update('/');
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('/');

        });
it('result function should exist', function() {
            update(7);
        update('+');
        update(8);
        result();
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('15');

        });
it('form_reset function should exist', function() {
            update(7);
        form_reset();
        expect(document.getElementById("screen").value).toBe('');
    });
    });
});
```

**Error that i am getting is :**

```
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.9.4) Calc Handson Calc  result function should exist FAILED                                                   
        SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /                                                                             
            at result (app/index.js:10:52)                                                                                             
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:88:6)                                                                       
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.9.4): Executed 16 of 16 (1 FAILED) (0.175 secs / 0.178 secs)
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `document.getElementById('screen').value = eval(text);` You sure what you are doing here?

Comment: Check the value of `text`, it more than likely is containing all the text from previous tests since it is never cleared. Eg it is probably ending up like `eval("1234567890*+-/7+8")` which gives the same error you are getting

Comment: Yes, the code works fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: HackerRank is probably entering invalid expressions that you didn't try in Visual Studio. You need to add error checking in `result()`.

Comment: Using eval is a pretty bad idea in any case. I'd go after creating a stack of entries and then case logic to determine the results rather than eval a string in any case.

Comment: Some notes on your JS: if you're using modern Node, you probably want to use modern JS with your HTML, too. So no `onclick=...` in the HTML itself, but assigning `id` attributes and then using `document.getElementById(...).addEventListener("click", evt => update(evt.target.value))`. And on the HTML side, unless you're breaking text, you should never see a `<br>` because CSS lets you specify spacing much more accurately. So if your teacher came up with this, point them to this comment. They gave you questionable code as starting point.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: This is not his code. Hakerrank is sort of like a competition - but usually meant to rank you for a job interview. You are given the `onclick=...` etc. YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE THEM.

Comment: You're not allowed to tell the people who are interviewing you that their code is no longer correct with respects to modern practice? Just because you can't change it is no excuse not to point out it's bad code.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. Below solution from @Trincot solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `text` is not reset between the different tests of the test suite. The test suite only resets the HTML, not the global variables you might have used. Although your idea to store the expression in a variable is great, you need a way that does not depend on global variables.

So, the idea could be to just store the expression in the `screen` element (not just the last digit that was entered)

This is what that comes down to:

```
function update(value) {
    document.getElementById('screen').value += value;
}

function result() {
    document.getElementById('screen').value = eval(document.getElementById('screen').value);
}

function form_reset() {
    document.getElementById('screen').value = "";
}
```